PyMC sampling getting nan or -inf from model sampling
I am getting a -inf or nan value from my PyMC model and wanted some help to debug it and figure out where the problem is. Here is my model:
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
## PyMC Model
# ---------------------------------------------------------------

# ---------------------------------------------------------------
# Define the time points for the simulated data
t_span = [0, 0.5]
t_eval = np.linspace(t_span[0], t_span[1], 100)
# Initial Conditions of the ODE
Ca0 = 50
Y0 = [Ca0]
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
# Define the ODE system to solve using PyMC
pymc_nuts_ode = DifferentialEquation(
    func=NS.rhs_swapped             ,  # The ODE system to solve
    times=noisy_data.time.values    ,  # Array of time points to solve the ODE at
    n_states=1                      ,  # Dimension of the ODE (number of dependent variables)
    n_theta=2                       ,  # Dimension of theta (number of parameters)
    t0=noisy_data.time.values[0]    ,  # The initial time
)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
# Prior means (informative priors - true values)
k = 0.18
alpha = 2
theta = [k, alpha]
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
# PyMC Model
with pm.Model() as model:
    # Priors
        # theta - parameters of the ODE
    k = pm.TruncatedNormal('k', mu=theta[0], sigma=0.01, lower=0, initval=theta[0])
    alpha = pm.TruncatedNormal('alpha', mu=theta[1], sigma=0.1, lower=0, initval=theta[1])
    theta = [k, alpha]
        # y0 - initial conditions
    Ca0 = pm.TruncatedNormal('Ca0', mu=Y0[0], sigma=0.1, lower=0 , initval=Y0[0])
    y0 = [Ca0]
    # Ca0 = pm.ConstantData('Ca0', value=Y0[0])


        # ODE solution
    ode_solution = pymc_nuts_ode(theta=theta, y0=y0)

    # Likelihood
    # ode_solution = pymc_nuts_ode(theta=[k, alpha], y0=[Ca0])
        # sigma - standard deviation for the likelihood
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal('sigma', 1)
        # Likelihood of the ODE solution
    likelihood = pm.Normal("Y_obs", mu=ode_solution, sigma=sigma, observed=noisy_data[["Ca"]].values) 

Sampling with either NUTS or Slice gives me the same problem with -inf or nan for my Y_obs variable:
# ----------------------------------------
## Slice Sampler
# ----------------------------------------

# Variable list to give to the sample step parameter
vars_list = list(model.values_to_rvs.keys())[:-1]

# Specify the sampler
sampler = 'Slice Sampler'
tune = draws = 1000

if __name__ == '__main__':
    model.debug()
    trace_slice = NS.run_model_slice(vars_list=vars_list, model=model, tune=tune, draws=draws, chains=4, cores=4)
    # Plot
    az.summary(trace_slice)
    az.plot_trace(trace_slice, kind="rank_bars")
    plt.suptitle(f"Trace Plot {sampler}")
    plt.tight_layout()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
NS.plot_inference(data=noisy_data, ax=ax, trace=trace_slice, title=f"Posterior Inference {sampler}")

The variable Y_obs has the following parameters:
0: DifferentialEquation{func=<function rhs_swapped at 0x000001DFD3A4E8E0>, times=(0.0, 0.005050505050505051, 0.010101010101010102, 0.015151515151515152, 0.020202020202020204, 0.025252525252525256, 0.030303030303030304, 0.03535353535353536, 0.04040404040404041, 0.045454545454545456, 0.05050505050505051, 0.05555555555555556, 0.06060606060606061, 0.06565656565656566, 0.07070707070707072, 0.07575757575757576, 0.08080808080808081, 0.08585858585858587, 0.09090909090909091, 0.09595959595959597, 0.10101010101010102, 0.10606060606060606, 0.11111111111111112, 0.11616161616161617, 0.12121212121212122, 0.12626262626262627, 0.13131313131313133, 0.13636363636363638, 0.14141414141414144, 0.14646464646464646, 0.15151515151515152, 0.15656565656565657, 0.16161616161616163, 0.16666666666666669, 0.17171717171717174, 0.1767676767676768, 0.18181818181818182, 0.18686868686868688, 0.19191919191919193, 0.196969696969697, 0.20202020202020204, 0.2070707070707071, 0.21212121212121213, 0.21717171717171718, 0.22222222222222224, 0.2272727272727273, 0.23232323232323235, 0.2373737373737374, 0.24242424242424243, 0.2474747474747475, 0.25252525252525254, 0.2575757575757576, 0.26262626262626265, 0.2676767676767677, 0.27272727272727276, 0.2777777777777778, 0.2828282828282829, 0.2878787878787879, 0.29292929292929293, 0.297979797979798, 0.30303030303030304, 0.3080808080808081, 0.31313131313131315, 0.31818181818181823, 0.32323232323232326, 0.3282828282828283, 0.33333333333333337, 0.3383838383838384, 0.3434343434343435, 0.3484848484848485, 0.3535353535353536, 0.3585858585858586, 0.36363636363636365, 0.36868686868686873, 0.37373737373737376, 0.37878787878787884, 0.38383838383838387, 0.3888888888888889, 0.393939393939394, 0.398989898989899, 0.4040404040404041, 0.4090909090909091, 0.4141414141414142, 0.4191919191919192, 0.42424242424242425, 0.42929292929292934, 0.43434343434343436, 0.43939393939393945, 0.4444444444444445, 0.44949494949494956, 0.4545454545454546, 0.4595959595959596, 0.4646464646464647, 0.4696969696969697, 0.4747474747474748, 0.47979797979797983, 0.48484848484848486, 0.48989898989898994, 0.494949494949495, 0.5), n_states=1, n_theta=2, t0=0.0}.0 [id A] <Matrix(float64, shape=(?, ?))>
 ├─ MakeVector{dtype='float64'} [id B] <Vector(float64, shape=(1,))>
 │  └─ Exp [id C] <Scalar(float64, shape=())> 'Ca0'
 │     └─ Ca0_interval__ [id D] <Scalar(float64, shape=())>
 └─ MakeVector{dtype='float64'} [id E] <Vector(float64, shape=(2,))>
    ├─ Exp [id F] <Scalar(float64, shape=())> 'k'
    │  └─ k_interval__ [id G] <Scalar(float64, shape=())>
    └─ Exp [id H] <Scalar(float64, shape=())> 'alpha'
       └─ alpha_interval__ [id I] <Scalar(float64, shape=())>
1: Exp [id J] <Scalar(float64, shape=())> 'sigma'
 └─ sigma_log__ [id K] <Scalar(float64, shape=())>
c:\Users\---\anaconda3\envs\pymc_env\Lib\site-packages\pymc\ode\ode.py:130: ODEintWarning: Excess accuracy requested (tolerances too small). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
  sol = scipy.integrate.odeint(
c:\Users\---\anaconda3\envs\pymc_env\Lib\site-packages\pymc\ode\ode.py:130: ODEintWarning: Excess accuracy requested (tolerances too small). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
  sol = scipy.integrate.odeint(
The parameters evaluate to:
0: [[5.00000000e+001]
 [5.04159234e+001]
 [5.04159234e+001]
 [1.39736850e-076]
 [9.16442737e-072]
 [3.24249365e-086]
 [7.86207943e-067]
 [1.05177001e-153]
 [1.74349530e-076]
 [1.05206420e-153]
 [2.21420214e-052]
 [6.98347617e-077]
 [7.27131731e-043]
 [3.24249370e-086]
 [2.52742153e-052]
 [1.30354289e-076]
 [1.48440629e-076]
 [9.72377416e-072]
 [1.17767151e-047]
 [1.24475475e-047]
 [4.18108097e-062]
 [2.74073548e-057]
 [1.38294297e-047]
 [1.45136677e-047]
...
 value = 30.99585709980524 -> logp = nan
 value = 30.065105897128564 -> logp = nan

I gave the slice samlping as the example because both the slice and NUTS give the same problem. I believe my priors to be well specified, and the mean values used are the 'true' values used to generate the data.
I have a working model of the Lotka-Voltera model from the documentation with all the different sampling methods used there and this error did not pop up there.
Any help in fixing this would be appreciated.
I have no place to start.
Edit:
The NS object is a python script with some plotting functions, and a function for the rhs of the ode and running the model. Below are the functions excludingplotting functions:
def rhs_swapped(Y, t, theta):
    """
    Right-hand side of the ODE system.
    """
    # Y = [0 = Ca]
    # theta = [0 = k , 1 = alpha]

    # Differential equations
    # dCadt = -theta[0] * Y[0] ** theta[1]
    dCadt = pow((-theta[0] * Y[0]), theta[1])
    dYdt = [dCadt] # Vector of derivatives
    return dYdt

def run_model_slice(vars_list, model, tune, draws, chains=4, cores=4):
    with model:
        trace = pm.sample(step=[pm.Slice(vars_list)], tune=tune, draws=draws, chains=chains, cores=cores)
    return trace

def run_model_nuts(model, tune, draws):
    with model:
        trace = pm.sample(tune=tune, draws=draws)
    return trace



What is the NS module/object that you are using?

a script that contains the rhs function, and some plotting functions (similar plotting to how the documentation for PyMC did it in their Lotka-Volttera examples). Check the edit part of the question, thank you
